# Am receiving more than thousand mails in single day from 'sample@email.tst' continuously

Tags: forms, sql, email, hacked

Am using 'WP Offload SES Lite' Plugin to collect Question & Answer through forms. But yesterday I was receiving thousands of mail in a single day continuously. I think someone tried to hack the site. Can you please tell me how to protect from these kinds of attacks?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a spambot, I would look into how you've implemented forms and adding a captcha of some kind or another anti-spam mechanism. Keep in mind though that 3rd party plugin support is off topic here

Comment: I've had a similar incident happen to me. These come from a company that scans your site for XSS and other vulnerabilities. It's marketed as a service to help you secure your own site, but could easily be abused to find vulnerabilities on any site. If you look through some of the messages, you'll likely find the URL "bxss.me" which redirects to "www.acunetix.com/vulnerability-scanner/acumonitor-technology/"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a reCaptcha to your form, follow this tutorial:

https://formidableforms.com/add-recaptcha-wordpress-contact-forms/